# Functions inside a Django model

Tags: django, django-models

Is it possible to write custom functions inside a Django model? And if it is, how can I do it properly. I'm currently doing a practice project of an ecommerce, and I want to change a boolean field value based on the value of an integer field. I currently have this:

```
class Product(Model):
   name = CharField(max_length=64)
   desc = CharField(max_length=256)
   price = DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
   available = BooleanField(default=True)
   quantity = IntegerField()
   category = ManyToManyField(Category)

   def availability(self):
       if self.quantity == 0:
           self.available = False
           self.save()
       return self.available

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

I know that I'm not calling the function, but I want that to be called once the product is updated even on the admin panel, is that possible to do?

And I'm not really confident about that *return* in the function, I don't feel like that is correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: About your comment "not confident about that return".... Very often in Django, if you end up overriding a base method (such as the save() that the answer below suggest you override), you will often make a call like super().save(*args, **kwargs), especially when you're just making a tweak to the base method (like setting an attribute before moving on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved in two ways, using the `save` method of the `model class` or by  using `save_model` method of `admin class`.

This is a demonstration by using `save()` method of `model class`

```
class Product(Model):
   name = CharField(max_length=64)
   desc = CharField(max_length=256)
   price = DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
   available = BooleanField(default=True)
   quantity = IntegerField()
   category = ManyToManyField(Category)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if self.quantity == 0:
           self.available = False
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: To add: you probably shouldn't return anything from that function, and should call it something like `set_availability`. Also, this code will lead to infinite recursion, so I would've removed the `save` from the `set_availability`. Another thing to think - do you (@MBsola) even need the field `available` - it can be a @property or a plain function

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov Thanks for the suggestion, I have done some changes, is that right now?